# Book reference for introduction to Normed Spaces

Tags: soft-question, normed-spaces, book-recommendation

I wanted a book reference for the study of normed spaces and linear operators. Im still not into functional analysis, but I wanted a reference of an introductory book as to start reading. What would you recommend?

I've have been studying for a while now metric spaces, and related concepts such as connection, completeness, compactness, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think that [Introductory Functional Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471504599), by Erwin Kreyszig is the book you want. The book is elementary, and as the title says, introductory. I even think you have some advantage there, having studied a bit of metric spaces before. The first chapter is about metric spaces, and he doesn't assume that you know anything about normed spaces.